# Wrong output after iterating vector in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create the program, that coverts number into digits written by words.

Example: n = 1321 -> output: "one"-'three"-"two"-"one"

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int digits(int number){
    int digits = 0;
    while (number != 0){number /= 10; digits++;}
    return digits;
    }


int main(){
    int num,remainder,i;
    int digits(int);
    vector<string> num_str = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    cin >> num;
    int length = digits(num);
    vector<int> num_int(length);
    while(num > 0){
        remainder = num % 10;
        num_int.push_back(remainder);
        num /= 10;
    }
    for(i = 0;i<num_int.size();++i){
        if(i == (num_int.size() - 1)){
            cout << num_str[num_int[i]];
        }else{
            cout << num_str[num_int[i]] <<"-";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example I enter:43 and I got output: "zero-zero-four-three".
And the number of "zero" is always equal to number of digits in number.
How can I fix it?

Comment: What debugging have you done already? This should be fairly easy to fix by running through it with a debugger, or even just using print debugging.

Comment: Add code before the `while` loop to show the contents of the array.

Comment: `vector<int> num_int(length);` creates length zeros. Then you push_back your calculations.

Comment: `vector<int> num_int(length);` then issue a `std::cout << num_int.size() << '\n';` directly after that line.  See anything strange?  Hint -- num_int size is not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to have 'digits' extraction the way you did it or do you want just to print numbers as strings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string const nums[10] = { "zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine" };

    long long num;
    std::cin >> num;

    std::string const numStr = std::to_string(num);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numStr.length(); ++i)
        std::cout << (i > 0 ? "-" : "") << "\"" << nums[numStr[i] - 48] << "\"";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```